# Hash tree with single branch

Tags: ruby, activesupport

Is there some convenient way to convert array

```
[a,b,c]
```

to hash-tree structure but only with one single branch, like so:

```
{node: {a: {node: {b: {node: :c}}}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `reduce` to get the result:

```
l = [:a, :b, :c]
t = l.reverse.reduce{|h,v|{v=>{node:h}}}  # {:a=>{:node=>{:b=>{:node=>:c}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that will do:

```
 a=[:a,:b,:c]
 l=lambda{|ar| if ar.empty? then 
        {}
    else 
        ar.length==1 ? {:node=>ar[0]} : {:node=> {ar.shift => (l.call ar)}}
    end
  }
 puts l.call a
```

Not sure if there's any easier way.

**UPD:** whoops, didnt notice it has something to do with ActiveSupport. Anyway, converting this hash to the structure you need shouldnt be difficult.